# Geoevent Manager setting up

Tags: arcgis-server, geoevent-processor

I set up Geoevent Manager and licensed with Geoevent license. As I saw on screenshot, there is Geoevent license in License authorization page in ArcGIS Server Manager site.

It shows that I licensed with Geoevent Server license. But this server manager is working as GIS Server.. I can't see Geoevent Manager on homepage. You can see on this picture, on homepage, it's written " ArcGIS Server Manager" not "Geoevent Manager"
[image]

Also I can't see monitor or inputs or anything belongs to Geoevent Manager. [image]

On the screenshot, there is no inputs, connectors or monitors. I installed Geoevent by using normal ArcGIS Server Manager setup. Then, like geoanalytics setup, I licensed with Geoevent manager. But it looks like still just GIS Server, not Geoevent Manager. How can i change this? Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

GeoEvent still requires a separate installer at 10.5. 
http://server.arcgis.com/en/geoevent/latest/install/windows/installing-geoevent.htm

(Whereas with Geoanalytics which is part of the ArcGIS Server install)

After installing you can access the GeoEvent manager via
https://gisserver.domain.com:6143/geoevent/manager/